# How to subscribe to a nested property in a observable collection in ReactiveUI

Tags: mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

How do i subscribe to a nested property in a observable collection?

view Model:

```
Public Class ViewModel{

    //a collection of all Hardware Tests.
    public observableCollection<HWTest> AllHWTests;


    //constructors
    ViewModel{

    //here I want to subscribe to Ispassed changes.
    
    }



}
```

HWTest:

```
public class HWTest{

    //a Collection of all Hardware types, each element have a isPassed property 
    //of  type bool.
    observableCollection<HWInterface> AllSignals;
}
```

HWInterface:

```
public Class HWInterface{

    //the property I would like to subscribe to at the view model
    public bool isPassed;

}
```

how do I subscribe  to the isPassed?

this is only an example, I didn't wrote any code at the moment.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please write more complete code for the current one I don't understand your problem.

Comment: thanks , I edited the code, I cant figure out how to subscribe to the isPassed property in the viewmodel class.

Comment: @BarakD - Do you mean `ObservableCollection<HWTest>` or `IObservable<HWTest>`? You can't subscribe to an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: I am new to reactiveui so i use the Observablecollection to observe all the HWTest i have in the view model,

Comment: @BarakD - Which doesn't answer my question.  Do you mean `ObservableCollection<HWTest>` or `IObservable<HWTest>`? You can't subscribe to an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: ObservableCollection<HWTest>, my goal is to subscribe to isPassed which is a property of  HWInterface.

Comment: @BarakD - You can't subscribe to a `ObservableCollection<HWTest>`. Do you mean attaching to the `CollectionChanged` event?

Comment: I didnt though about this direction, can work, but the problem is the event will fire only if the collection gets Added, Deleted,Refreshed, i need to monitor Ispassed changes,

Comment: @BarakD - So, let me see if I've got this, you have a collection of objects that implement the `HWInterface` interface, and you want to get a notification when any one `isPassed` changes? Do you care which object's property changes or do you want to know which one did?

Comment: I want to know which objects property changed

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableCollection<T>` only lets you observable the changes of membership of the collection. You need to use that to attach to events that each class member implements to see when the individual properties are changing in the members of the collection.

Here's how to use (1) `ObservableCollection<T>` and also (2) `IObservable<T>` to do what you're asking.

First we need to set up the class that we want to observe:

```
public class HWInterface : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    public HWInterface(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    
    private bool _isPassed = false;
    public bool IsPassed
    {
        get => _isPassed;
        set
        {
            if (_isPassed != value)
            {
                _isPassed = value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsPassed"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note I've changed your casing to use the normal C# idiomatic form.

Now I need an `ObservableCollection<HWInterface>` to work with:

```
var oc = new ObservableCollection<HWInterface>();
```

For (1) I need this code to watch the items in the collection:

```
PropertyChangedEventHandler pceh = (s, e)  => Console.WriteLine($"1: {(s as HWInterface).Name} \"{e.PropertyName}\" changed to {(s as HWInterface).IsPassed}.");

oc.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.NewItems != null) foreach (var f in e.NewItems.OfType<HWInterface>()) f.PropertyChanged += pceh;
    if (e.OldItems != null) foreach (var f in e.OldItems.OfType<HWInterface>()) f.PropertyChanged -= pceh;
};
```

For (2) I need this code to watch the items in the collection:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
            h => oc.CollectionChanged += h,
            h => oc.CollectionChanged -= h)
        .Select(x =>
            oc
                .ToObservable()
                .SelectMany(f =>
                    Observable
                        .FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                            h => f.PropertyChanged += h,
                            h => f.PropertyChanged -= h)
                        .Select(y => new { foo = f, property = y.EventArgs.PropertyName })))
        .Switch();
        
IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"2: {x.foo.Name} \"{x.property}\" changed to {x.foo.IsPassed}."));
```

Now I can run some test code:

```
var a = new HWInterface("A");
var b = new HWInterface("B");
var c = new HWInterface("C");

oc.Add(a);
oc.Add(b);
oc.Add(c);

b.IsPassed = true;

b.IsPassed = false;

oc.Remove(b);

b.IsPassed = true; // `b` has been removed so doesn't fire anymore
c.IsPassed = true;
```

Here's my output:

```
1: B "IsPassed" changed to True.
2: B "IsPassed" changed to True.
1: B "IsPassed" changed to False.
2: B "IsPassed" changed to False.
1: C "IsPassed" changed to True.
2: C "IsPassed" changed to True.
```

Answer (score -1):

Out of the Box `ObservableCollection` does not provide you what you want.  It's name suggests you can observe things internal to the list (The INotifyPropertyChangedEvent of the elements on the list).

Generally, we want to know `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` for a given `ObservableCollection` which requires some manual setup.  I wrote a [blog](https://rodneylittlesii.com/posts/topic/inotifycollectionchanged) on this topic.

TLDR

What you want to use is [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactivemarbles/DynamicData).  It will allow you to obtain property changed notifications from internal elements of the list.